# Passing response data (res.json) from an express route to a react axios post method

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

```
axios({
  url: 'myurl.com',
  method: 'post',
  data:data,})
    .then(function(response) {
      this.setState({auth:response}); //this is where I want to send express response to
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
```

Here is my axios call that passes user input to my express route.

```
app.post('myurl.com', function(req,res) {
  const user = req.body.data
  const pass = req.body.otherData
  const token = await db.call(req,res,user,pass)
  \\ res.json = token ?
})
```

And here is the express route that uses the user input to query the db. This is where I want to set the result of the db query to a variable and send it back to the axios call as a response. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close

```
app.post('myurl.com', function(req,res) {
  const user = req.body.data
  const pass = req.body.otherData
  const token = await db.call(req,res,user,pass)
  res.status(200).send({token})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) statement should be inside of [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
app.post('myurl.com', async function(req,res) { //add async to function

//put await statement inside try/catch
  try{

      const token = await db.call(req,res,user,pass)
      res.json({token}) //use json function from resp to send json response

  }catch(error){
      res.json({error})
  }
})
```